# Show that $P(\vert \frac{X}{n}-p\vert >a) \le \frac{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}{a^2 n} \min{(\sqrt{p(1-p)},a \sqrt{n})}$

Tags: probability-theory

Show that $P(\vert \frac{X}{n}-p\vert >a) \le \frac{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}{a^2 n} \min{(\sqrt{p(1-p)},a \sqrt{n})}$ where $X$ is a binomial $B(n,p)$ with $p>0$ fixed and $a>0$.

I tried to use the Chebyshev's inequality but, clearly it does not work as it gives me
$P(\vert \frac{X}{n}-p\vert >a) \le P(\vert \frac{X}{n}-p\vert \ge a) \le \frac{p(1-p)}{a^2 n}$.

I suspect that this is a stronger result and Chebyshev inequality isn't enough. Any hints on how could I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is good. If we also show $P(|\frac{X}{n} - p| > a) \le \frac{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}{a \sqrt{n}}$ then combining this with your result solves the problem.

Hint: start with Markov's inequality instead of Chebychev, and then use Jensen's inequality.

> \begin{align}P\left(\left|\frac{X}{n} - p\right| > a\right) &\le \frac{1}{a} E\left|\frac{X}{n} - p\right| \\ &\le \frac{1}{a} \sqrt{E\left[\left(\frac{X}{n} - p\right)^2\right]} \\ &= \frac{1}{a} \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X/n)}\\ & = \frac{1}{a} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}.\end{align}

Comment: Ah Jenson;s inequality did the trick .I was trying to explicitly compute $E[\vert X-np\vert]$ but I couldnt find a nice summation formula to show the result. Thank you

Comment: is there a way to do  it without the Jenson;s/Holder's inequality ? Its not treated in the book (which is chapter 5)